# Ice in contact with a heat reservoir at $0^\circ \textrm{C}$?

Tags: thermodynamics

Let us say I put ice starting at a temperature $T \lt 0^\circ \textrm{C}$, and held at constant pressure of $1atm$ in contact with an infinite heat reservoir at temperature exactly  $0^\circ \textrm{C}$. When we have reached an equilibrium state will we have just ice, water and ice, or just water?

I doubt the answer is going to be just water, but between the other two I do not know.

Comment: @lemon Can you give your specific reasons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TL;DR): If the ice has surfaces then it will completely melt to form water. If the ice has no surfaces (it's infinitely large) then it will remain completely ice.

Here's the reasoning:

If we imagine an **idealised system** that is infinitely large in extent (i.e. no surfaces and therefore no heterogeneous nucleation) then the ice will remain in an ice state, with small water nuclei that spontaneously form and then disappear again. To see why, consider how the free energy changes when a water nucleus of radius $r$ forms:

$$ \Delta G=-\Delta G_V (4\pi r^3/3) + \gamma(4\pi r^2) $$

where $\Delta G_V$ is the difference in free energy between the bulk phases, and $\gamma$ is the surface free energy. At the coexistence point, $\Delta G_V=0$ by definition, and so the the growth of a water phase will only ever cost energy (i.e. there's no critical size). The size distribution of these random water droplets will be given by the Boltzmann distribution:

$$ P\propto \exp(-4\pi r^2 \gamma/k_BT) $$

In the **real world**, the ice will have surfaces. And the surface energy of ice is greater than that of water, so the outer layers will melt, resulting in a block of ice surrounded by a layer of water. As before, since neither bulk phase is preferred, then the system will move towards the state that minimises the interfacial free energy, and so the ice in the core will shrink in size until it disappears.

The result is pure water with tiny ice nuclei spontaneously forming and melting with the same size distribution as before ($P\propto \exp(-4\pi r^2 \gamma/k_BT)$).

Comment: One could also find the same result by considering entropy. Since liquid water has higher entropy at 0C than ice, random fluctuations will eventually melt the ice.

Comment: @Echows Not true. Entropy may favour water but enthalpy favours ice by an equal amount. And when you consider the free energy, neither the bulk water nor the bulk ice is favoured. It's all down to the free energy of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The ice would rise to the same temperature as the reservoir (0 C).  Once it got to that temperature, there would be no more driving force for heat transfer, and the system would be in equilibrium.  So it would be the same as if you took any solid block of any material at T < 0 C and put it in contact with an ideal infinite reservoir at 0 C.  There would be transient conduction within the block until the system equilibrated at 0 C.

Comment: My answer disagrees with this; let me know if you see any fault in my reasoning.

Comment: I am not able to follow your analysis.  Are you saying that, if I put ice at 0 C into an adiabatic container with a huge amount of water at 0 C and allow the system to equilibrate, basically all the ice will melt?

Comment: If the volume of water is large enough, yes. Would you agree that a decrease in the size of the ice (in particular, the surface area) will correspond to a decrease in free energy?

Comment: What if the original ice were sealed in a plastic bag so that it did not directly contact the surrounding water in the reservoir?  (The OP didn't say anything about the reservoir being water at 0 C.  It could have been some entirely different reservoir liquid, not even in direct contact with the ice.)

Comment: The surface of the ice will melt to form a thin layer of water (which is why ice is slippery) and you're left with the same situation; ice surrounded by water. So yes, it will still melt.

Comment: Suppose the bag were adiabatic so that no heat could enter or leave.  Would a layer of liquid still form then and, if so, where would the heat of fusion come from?  If the ice particle in the plastic bag were spherical with a diameter of 1 cm (and the bag were not adiabatic), how thick would the water layer be (quantitatively please)?

Comment: A very thin layer, yes: the heat of fusion would be provided by the energy gained from the reduction in surface energy. But you've in/advertently removed the heat reservoir so the ice would not melt any further than this thin layer.

Comment: @lemon Within the context of the OP's question, in your best practical judgment, do you really feel that this minor surface affect that causes a very thin layer of liquid water to form at the surface of the ice body (as yet unquantified by you) would be deemed significant by the OP, or would you judge that he was thinking on a larger physical scale than this?  It is nice to be aware of physical nuances, but sometimes focusing on these only adds to an OP's confusion.

Comment: It's hard to be precise without effort but the layer will indeed be small, ~1 nm in thickness. But this is by no means a nuance: the free energy will be the surface free energy of *water* plus the water-ice interface (the bulk is irrelevant). And therefore the free energy will be minimised if the interface reduces in size. So water will be the *thermodynamically* stable phase.

Comment: Based on the OP's original question, you don't consider that negligible?  @Quantum spaghettification, how would you weight in on this?  Would you consider a 1 nm layer of liquid water on the surface of the ice as something pretty significant relative to your original question?

Comment: Let's step back a minute. Would you agree with my previous claim that ice in a sufficiently large ocean of water at 0 C will completely melt?

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.  He said nothing about the chemical characteristics of the reservoir, and was referring only to the *thermal* interaction of the ice with the reservoir.  My inclination is not to respond here further.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Lemon is Practically correct (-> Water), but I want to give another approach; QED.

First we need just to think **what is HEAT?** It's just kinetic "jiggling" of atoms. The carousel is rotating faster/with bigger radius when there is more heat.

**What is melting of ice?** (Or what is Solid-liquid change on state in matter?) It's the process where the atoms starts to flow freely compared to each other.

The basic question here is; Does a single molecule "know" if it's solid or if it's liquid. The Answer is of course; **it doesn't**, there is no difference to single atom if it's part of solid / liquid / gas / plasma. It's merely an issue of enough electromagnetic forces able to hold the molecule in it's position compared to others.

This thinking can be brought even below the molecule-level. Water molecule $H_2O$ is 2x Hydrogen + 1 x Oxygen. And with normal flowing water, the hydrogen atom doesn't even know which oxygen atom it's supposed to form the molecule with. And [thus in fluid the hydrogen bonds are continually breaking and reforming at timescales faster than 200 femtoseconds.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#Physics_and_chemistry)

This is the major difference of Solid ice and liquid water; on solid-ice the atoms are locked on the lattice structure.

**Answer;** The whole ice will turn in to water over time, because at melting temperature, the Heat of hydrogen is too great; there is nothing which would maintain the lattice structure; not even in idealized infinitely large system. The Melting will happen spontaneously throughout the whole matter, according to QED probabilities if there just is the needed Heat provided to keep up this process.

Answer (score -1):

Since the heat reservoir has exactly 0 deg. the ice would heat to reach the same temperature, but ideally it would not change since it's directly the freezing/melting point. Melting ice would require additional energy.

**In case of being submerged in water at freezing point:**

It depends on the initial temperature of ice. Since the thermal equilibrium is 0 deg. C. the ice would heat up to 0 deg. 
The energy lost by ice would be consumed by water for phase transition, thus creating additional ice layer.

Simple response: the amount of ice would increase depending on initial ice temperature.

Comment: The ice content would *increase*? Are you imagining the ice to be physically submerged in an ocean? Because that's not what is meant by an idealised heat reservoir...

Comment: Right, for some reason I took heat reservoir for a water container. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Melting the ice would not require additional work because the two bulk phases have the same free energy. The melting of the ice corresponds to the interface shrinking in size (and therefore a reduction in surface free energy).